# Trying to pass images between view controllers

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell on VC1 that contains, an imageView, a label and a button.

How can i send the image contained in the imageView on VC1 to an imageView in VC2 on the tap of that button?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: @rmaddy i referred to the link, and followed steps. The error i am getting is that the label outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: @rmaddy i have those outlets saved in an array already. how can i send it?

Answer (score 0):

You set UIImage objecte in VC2 and on push or present viewcontroler time vc2.image = vc1.imageview.image use than set UIImage on UIImageView on Viewdidload event

Comment: i am getting "Cannot connect to repeating content" error, i already have the stuff in the collection view saving to an array.

Comment: in vc2 i did `var receivedStr = ""` i added `viewDidLoad()` to have `label.text = receivedStr` then in VC1 i connected my label in the collection view cell to an outlet and in `prepareForSegue` i did `vc2.receivedStr = nameLabel.text`